# ActiveMQ Artemis JMS Provider Class-Path configuration

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have updated ActiveMQ Artemis to address vulnerabilities, and it is currently running on version 2.31.2. We have specified the JMS provider for connecting to ActiveMQ Artemis from WebSphere:

[image]

My doubt is whether the classpath I have provided for a few JAR files is suitable for ActiveMQ Artemis 2.31.2. Is it fine, or do I need to use any extra JAR files? Additionally, will ActiveMQ Artemis 2.31.2 support these JAR versions?

Currently we are providing:

- activemq-client-5.14.5.jar
- hawbuf-1.11.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're using the OpenWire JMS client implementation from ActiveMQ Classic 5.14.5 (which is quite old). According to the [Maven dependencies for the `activemq-client`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-client/5.14.5) module you've covered everything you need to:

```xml
    <!-- =============================== -->
    <!-- Required Dependencies -->
    <!-- =============================== -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fusesource.hawtbuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>hawtbuf</artifactId>
      <version>${hawtbuf-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

To be clear, you don't need to include the JMS specification jar file because that's already provided implicitly by WebSphere.

Keep in mind that you could upgrade the OpenWire JMS client to something newer (e.g. 5.18.3) or you could even switch to the core JMS client that ships with ActiveMQ Artemis, but that would require changing the context factory and the URL.

Comment: yes I am switched into core JMS client comes with the ActiveMQ Artemis(D:\apache-artemis-2.31.2-bin\apache-artemis-2.31.2\lib)
activemq-client-5.17.6.jar
hawtbuf-1.11.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
for this which context factory and the URL need to be use ? shall i use this "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"

Comment: You are using the libraries for the **OpenWire** JMS client, not the core JMS client. The only reason that ActiveMQ Artemis includes those libraries is because they are required to support OpenWire clients in migration scenarios. If you want to use the core JMS client the simplest thing would be to use the [`artemis-jms-client-all`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/artemis-jms-client-all/2.31.2/) library which also means you'd need to change the context factory to be `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`.

Comment: Any feedback here? Did my answer address your question?

Comment: OpenWire JMS client to something newer (e.g. 5.18.3) how to donwload the lastest jar fiCurrently using  activemq-client-5.17.6.jar hawtbuf-1.11.jar slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar